# How to know internet become active after disconnection in iPhone app

Tags: ios, uitableview, internet-connection

I have created an tableview that shows RSSS. I check for internet connection then get RSS feeds to load into tableview and  if internet is unavailable it shows network error alert ands empty tableview is shown. But I want to load tableview when internet connection become active.
**Is there any way to know when internet connection becomes active after disconnection in iPhone app.**

Comment: a nice example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3597085/653513

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the Reachability class.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html